# frida hook jni not work

Tags: android, function-hooking

I want to trace Android Telegram app(open-source) to learn its protocol.

From the source code these two functions `AES_set_encrypt_key` and `AES_ctr128_encrypt` are used to do the encryption, and I can verify that these two functions are called when sending packets because the **frida-trace** can log and print the call:

`frida-trace -U -i AES_ctr128_encrypt -i AES_set_encrypt_key org.telegram.messenger`.

So I try to hook them and print the parameters:

```
// telegram.js

Java.perform(function () {
    console.log('tg loaded');

    Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName ('libcrypto.so', 'AES_set_encrypt_key'), {
        onEnter: function(args) {
            console.log('enter 1');
        },
        onLeave: function (retval) {
        }
    });
    Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName ('libcrypto.so', "AES_ctr128_encrypt"), {
        onEnter: function(args) {
            console.log('enter 2');
        },
        onLeave: function (retval) {
        }
    });
});
```

And use this telegram.js like: `frida -U -l telegram.js org.telegram.messenger`

But the hook to `onEnter` is never called.

Comment: Can you share a link to the application?